# "not found: value classOf" error when building scala in IntelliJ IDEA, but builds correctly in maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, mockito

I have written a small piece of test code and am compiling it with IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE

```
import com.twitter.common.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient
import org.mockito.Mockito

    class MyResourceSpec { 
      val zkClient = mock(classOf[ZooKeeperClient])
      ...
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
not found: value classOf
  val zkClient = mock(classOf[ZooKeeperClient])
                 ^
```

However I am able to build the project successfully using mvn compile. Also, I have another test file in the same directory "MyOtherResourceSpec.scala" which contains the exact same lines of code.

Any thoughts on why this doesn't build correctly in IDEA?

Things I've tried:

- A coworker suggested that IDEA might not recognize it as a scala file, and I've tried clicking on the top-level project and then
  clicking Maven > reimport.
- Restarting IntelliJ
- Copying all imports from "MyOtherResourceSpec.scala" in case something was missing
- using Mockito.mock(classOf[ZooKeeperClient])

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I solved this by clicking **File > Invalidate Caches** and restarting IntelliJ. Then I did not need to import Predef.classOf.

I also had to remove the following import statement:

```
import scala.Predef.String
```

Comment: It seems indeed that if you import anything specific from `Predef`, the rest is not imported automatically. In my case, IntelliJ had automatically added such an import from `Predef`, which was causing a bunch of other things to fail in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `Predef.classOf`, that should help or just write `Predef.classOf`. IDEA uses it's own external compiler based on sbt, maybe there are some problems

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Oh - and it *works for me* !  I had the problem in the OP and invalidating caches - aside from blitzing my local history that is painful - did not work. This did. I do not respect some of the downvoters on this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Maven in offline mode**

I updated my project from version control which included an update to the Scala version.  Because I had Intellij Maven in offline mode it could not download the new Scala artifacts.

Putting Intellij Maven back online may fix the problem (for others like me).